# Quotient of ring is flat gives an identity of ideals

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals, flatness

I have problem to understand and solve the exercise 1.2.14 on Qing Liu's book "Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves". It goes as follows:

Let $A\to B$ be a ring homomorphism, and let $J$ be an ideal of $B$ such that $B/J$ is flat over $A$. Show that for any ideal $I$ of $A$, we have that $(IB)\cap J=IJ$ (tensor the injection $I\to A$ by $B/J$).

Where do we need the homomorphism $A\to B$ as Liu does not use it explicitly in the problem? Could someone elaborate why tensoring the injection helps to prove the theorem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't get Liu's hint, but the following it's useful and not hard to prove:

> Let $M$ be a flat $A$-module. Then if tensor a short exact sequence of $A$-modules $0\to M_1\to M_2\to M\to 0$ by any $A$-module it remains exact.

Now consider $0\to J\to B\to B/J\to 0$ a short exact sequence of $A$-modules. By tensoring this with $A/I$ we get $0\to J\otimes_AA/I\to B\otimes_AA/I\to B/J\otimes_AA/I\to 0$. We know that $J\otimes_AA/I\simeq J/IJ$, $B\otimes_AA/I\simeq B/IB$, and $B/J\otimes_AA/I\simeq B/(IB+J)$. (I've used here that $M\otimes_AA/I\simeq M/IM$.) This shows that $(IB+J)/IB\simeq J/(IB\cap J)=J/IJ$, and we are done.

Comment: A reference for the highlighted result: http://www.math.purdue.edu/~sbasu/teaching/fall08/557/Week6.pdf (Proposition 14).

Comment: I am a little confused about what is meant by $IJ$ here as $I$ and $J$ are ideals of different ring. We have the following result: If $R/I$ is a flat $R$ module, then for any ideal $J$ of $R$, $I\cap J=IJ$. Using this result in the above situation we get $J\cap IB=JIB$. THis could perhaps resolve your concern why the homomorphism $f$ is mentioned, $IB$ is the ideal generated by $f(I)$.

Comment: @user114539 Reading your comment up to the end, I don't think you are confused at all about the meaning of $IJ$. Anyway, one can use the result you mentioned as an "alternative" approach, but, of course, this should be proved, and what I did is more or less a proof for such a result.

Comment: You are correct, what you have proved more or less proves what I have used. As you notice, it is just a remark and not an answer.