# Flatness of $\frac{A[b]}{\langle u,v \rangle}$ over $A$ and flatness of $\frac{A[w]}{\langle u \rangle}$ over $A$

Tags: polynomials, commutative-algebra, jacobian, flatness

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic zero.
Let $A \subseteq B$ be two commutative $k$-algebras (which are integral domains) such that $B=A[b]$, for some $b \in B$, and $u,v \in B$.

Assume that:
**(i)** $\frac{B}{\langle u,v \rangle}$ is a flat $A$-module. 
**(ii)** $\frac{B}{\langle u \rangle}$ is a flat $A$-module
and $\frac{B}{\langle v \rangle}$ is a flat $A$-module.

> Is there something interesting that can be said about $A,B,u,v$?

Notice that $\frac{B}{\langle v \rangle} \to \frac{B}{\langle u,v \rangle}$ is surjective, but I do not see how this helps.

**Special case:**
The theorem presented [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3100323/flatness-criterion-for-a-finite-type-algebra-based-on-the-jacobian) implies the following (if I am not wrong):
If $p,q \in k[x,y]$ with $\operatorname{Jac}(p,q) \in k^{\times}$, then $\frac{k[x,y]}{\langle p,q \rangle}$ is flat as a $k[x]$-module and as a $k[y]$-module (take there $R=k[x]$ and $R=k[y]$).

Moreover, if we assume (this is possible by a change of variables) that $p,q$ are monic in $y$ (namely, $p=y^n+p_{n-1}y^{n-1}+\cdots+p_1y+p_0$, 
$q=y^n+q_{m-1}y^{m-1}+\cdots+q_1y+q_0$, where $p_i,q_j \in k[x]$),
then $\frac{k[x,y]}{\langle p \rangle}$ is flat over $k[x]$ 
and $\frac{k[x,y]}{\langle q \rangle}$ is flat over $k[x]$.
Similarly, $p,q$ are monic in $x$, so $\frac{k[x,y]}{\langle p \rangle}$ is flat over $k[y]$ 
and $\frac{k[x,y]}{\langle q \rangle}$ is flat over $k[y]$.
This claim follows from a result presented [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2190446/s-f-flat-iff-the-coefficients-of-f-generate-the-unit-ideal) (and is mentioned in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_module). Originally, it seems to be a result of [Nagata](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.kjm/1250523905)).

Therefore, this is indeed a special case with $A=k[x],B=k[x][y], u=p, v=q$ 
(or $A=k[y],B=k[y][x], u=p, v=q$).

See also the following questions: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3536084/flatness-of-a-fx-1-dots-x-n-f-1-dots-f-n?noredirect=1&lq=1), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1121711/quotient-of-ring-is-flat-gives-an-identity-of-ideals) and [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/487214/is-r-nr-a-faithfully-flat-r-module).

**Important remark:**  According to the first comment to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2319091/a-generalization-of-nagatas-flatness-theorem) question, which says: "... if $R$ is a UFD and $R[T]/I$ is flat over $R$, $I$ a proper ideal, then $I$ must be principal", it follows that $\langle p,q \rangle =\langle r \rangle$
for some $r \in k[x][y]$ (unless $\langle p,q \rangle =k[x][y]$). 
Then $p=Ur, q=Vr$ for some $U,V \in k[x,y]$. It follows that $r=\lambda \in k$
(since $\operatorname{Jac}(p,q) \in k^{\times}$), hence $\langle p,q \rangle =\langle r \rangle= \langle \lambda \rangle= k[x][y]$ after all.
Therefore, the Jacobian Conjecture is true, unless I have an error in my above arguments.

---

Any hints and comments are welcome; thank you!

Comment: For more details about the "important remark", please see https://www.researchgate.net/post/An_attempt_to_prove_the_Jacobian_Conjecture_any_comments_are_welcome